# Loading template parts conditionally in Customizer

Tags: conditional-tags, theme-customizer, get-template-part

Here are my issues:

I have layout options in customizer for full width or two columns. For fullwidth sidebar will not be loaded. The problem is if the setting is currently on full width when customizer loaded and then switch to two columns option the sidebar won't be there so it left a blank space in the sidebar.

I tried with is_customize_preview() function on my sidebar to always prepare the sidebar if its in the customize preview screen. But this cause another problem, the sidebar will also visible for full width layout.

So my current hack is using js to hide the sidebar and show it if two column, but this is an ugly way to switch sidebar preview since I need to trigger .change() when customizer is loaded also it will means to load unncessary template parts.

Is there a server side customizer api to allow conditionally loading a sidebar or template parts?

Comment: are you by any chance trying the use `'transport' => 'postMessage'` on that control? If yes, then try using `refresh` instead of `postMessage`

Comment: looks like your prayers have been answered in WP 4.5... https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/02/16/selective-refresh-in-the-customizer/

Comment: @majick Yappp!! that's what I'm looking for, partially refresh template parts :)

Comment: looks like a nice and fresh complexity.. good luck with it!